# Need an advanced Grid for .NET 3.5 WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, gridview

Possibly also for ASP.NET, but WinForms, for sure.

I'm reviewing a previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144338/what-is-the-best-third-party-winforms-grid-for-net and I am still not sure which one to look for necessarily, so will say what we're looking for.

We need a grid which can support advanced features like Grid in cell type of thing, I think. Necessarily should support sorting a Grid and what that all entails.

I say Grid in cell, because I'm envisioning a Grid with listed objects whose properties will be editable. So each object represents top-level Grid cell entries. Drill into that and the properties on each object should also be editable.

Or say it another way, Grid with collapsible view. [+] Object.

Or, plausibly Tree with Grids as nodes.

These are just some scribbled thoughts for the moment. I know what I have in mind and will know it when I see it. Of necessity, I must shop it around a little because we don't have very deep pockets. If I present a case, they'll go for it, so I want to make sure I've done my due diligence.

Chief candidates that I am aware of: XtraGrid (looks like it has Data Grouping, which is just what would work, I think). Telerik RadGridView. Don't know of any others just yet.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "WinForms". That's what we use tags for on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

I've used the DevExpress XtraGrid quite a bit and it works quite well for the sort of thing you are trying to do.  The other thing to keep in mind is that if you go with DevExpress, you can get complete set of WinForms controls.  They also have reporting and charting controls if you're interested in that sort of thing.  I would also add that DevExpress has very good documentation and technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely DotNetBar's DataGridViewX or their ListView control replacement

Answer (score 0):

This is a subjective answer, but it was a somewhat subjective question.

I worked with Telerik, both Web and Windows from 2006 - 2008 and, although it could look pretty, found it both heavy and the API relatively inconsistent and irritating.

I have worked with DevExpress XtraGrid since then and am much happier with it than Telerik, the API is for more consistent, and the functionality is far superior. Grouping is one such area I have not felt pain since switching.

DevExpress also have a tree grid that I don't recall Telerik having when I was using them.

I do acknowledge, however, that I am comparing Telerik then with DevExpress now, and I believe that Telerik has updated a bit since then. I have, however, no desire to go back to them.

I have no affiliation with either company.

Comment: Thanks for this objective subjective answer. Of course, I know it's subjective, somewhat a matter of preference trading off cost for quality, ease of use, etc. Mainly, I want to make a right decision so that my third-party vendor can be the control experts while I am freed up to be the application expert. That's what I'm aiming for anyhow.

Comment: One other observation at least as far as our usage goes. Grid is one aspect we'll need. Charting like you said, might could be useful. Don't know just yet, but in our application, I can easily see someone asking that type of question. GAUGES GAUGES GAUGES are a necessity; we'll need gauges. If such a library includes gauges, that wouldn't hurt selling it to our purchasers.

Comment: I only really ever played with gauges a couple of days ago, very nice, but we haven't any real use of them.